# JQuery .text() function returns the text value of the element on previous page while using breadcrumbs code

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I am using javascript code for **breadcrumb navigation**.

I want to extract the text value of the heading (h2) in my example.

I used **.text()** function to do so but the problem is:

When navigate to the next page, the script returns text value of the heading on the previous page and every time I navigate I need to refresh the page to get it works.

my code. on the page.php

> ```
>  <script language="JavaScript">
>
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> name=$("h2").text();      
>
> });
>
>
> breadcrumbs('index.php',name);// call the function
>
> </script>
>
>
>    <h2>Title</h2>
> ```

the javascript.js:

> ```
> // JavaScript Document
>
> function breadcrumbs(home,name){
>
>
>   sURL = new String;
>   bits = new Object;
>   var x = 0;
>   var stop = 0;
>   var output = "<a href=\"http\:\/\/"+home+"\">الرئيسية</a> \<b\>&raquo;\<\/b\>  ";
>   sURL = location.href;
>   sURL = sURL.slice(8,sURL.length);
>   chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
>   sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length)
>   while(!stop){
>     chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
>     if (chunkStart != -1){
>       bits[x] = sURL.slice(0,chunkStart)
>       sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length);
>     }else{
>       stop = 1;
>     }
>     x++;
>   }
>   for(var i in bits){
>     output += "<a href=\"";
>     for(y=1;y<x-i;y++){
>       output += "../";
>     }
>     output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i] + "</a>  \<b\> &raquo; \<\/b\>  ";
>   }
>
>
>
>   document.write(output + name);
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery selector `$('h2')` will be examining the whole dom (document object model) present in your browser. Your breadcrumbs will most likely keep your view content on the page and just toggle visibility. Have a look at your page via the inspect element option of your browser and you'll find that all the first page content is still there, despite toggling.

Give your html for each breadcrumb content and your respective headings class names or ids, then you can restrict your selector to the desired header.

Comment: do u mean  i should add id for each h2 ? or maybe use the desired text directly instead of 'name' without using jquery !!

Comment: You need some method of selecting specific headers. To do this, you need to give each header a defining characteristic in order to distinguish between them. You could of course give your breadcrumb content divs classnames such as `bc-content-1`, `bc-content-2` etc, and then use jquery to select your header like so `$('.bc-content-2 h2')`, or just give each header a different id and select them with jQuery by going `$('#<id>')` where `<id>` is the id of the desired header.

Comment: i have only one h2 on each page. i will try what you suggest and get back

Comment: its still the same .. i need to click the link 2 times to get the right page title!!

Comment: i used different id for each h2 element but still keeps the previous element value.. may be i need to use 'this' or sth like that in jquery script

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd love to help but as far as I can see you're having issues with a few very basic, very large components of javascript and client-side web development that are beyond the scope of a single question. Look into (in this order) javascript variable scoping, DOM, jQuery (in particular selectors).